# Regex to match a string that does not contain any words longer than 10 characters?

Tags: regex

```
^(.)+\S{10}(.)+$
```

I have that regex which will match any string that contains a word of 10 characters.
However I need the INVERSE of that.
A regex that will only match strings which do NOT have words of >=10 characters.

Comment: You might want to use \w ("word character") instead of \S ("not a space character").  The string "!@#$%^&*()!!!" would match \S{10,} but not \w{10,}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative assertion.

```
(?!.*\S{10})
```

`\S{10}` matches a sequence of 10 `\S` (which must be a subsequence of anything longer). `(?!pattern)` is a negative lookahead, an assertion that is true if the pattern doesn't match. `.*` allows the lookahead to look as far as necessary.

The whole pattern therefore is

```
^(?!.*\S{10}).*$
```

This matches all string that do NOT contain `\S{10}`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
^\s*\S{0,9}(\s+\S{1,9})*\s*$
```

Matches one or more words. The first word is optional, so the empty string or a string of all whitespace will match. The words must be separated by whitespace `\s+` so no more than 9 `\S` characters can ever be adjacent.